# forced to click on the textview to get the value

Tags: java, android, performance, arraylist, textview

I put a textview in an arraylist and I have to click on the texview so that the value is displayed. i would like the value to be displayed without i need to click on the textview. and when the value it changes, what is displayed in the texview is the old value, I have to click on the textview so that it updates the value

all displayed well except  :

```
holder.mTextprix.setText(CustomerMapActivity.calculate_item_price);
```

here my code

Adapter responsible for displaying type of cars in the CustomerActivity.class

```
public class TypeAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TypeAdapter.viewHolders> {

    private Context context;
    private TypeObject selectedItem;
    private List<TypeObject> itemArrayList;

    public TypeAdapter(List<TypeObject> itemArrayList, Context context) {
        this.itemArrayList = itemArrayList;
        selectedItem = itemArrayList.get(0);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public TypeAdapter.viewHolders onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_type, null, false);
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        TypeAdapter.viewHolders rcv = new TypeAdapter.viewHolders(layoutView);
        return rcv;
    }

    /**
     * Bind view to holder, setting the text to
     * the design elements
     * @param position - current position of the recyclerView
     */
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final @NonNull viewHolders holder, int position) {
        holder.mName.setText(itemArrayList.get(position).getName());
        holder.mPeople.setText(String.valueOf(itemArrayList.get(position).getPeople()));
        holder.mImage.setImageDrawable(itemArrayList.get(position).getImage());
        holder.mTextprix.setText(CustomerMapActivity.calculate_item_price);
        if(selectedItem.equals(itemArrayList.get(position))){
            holder.mLayout.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent2));
        }else{
            holder.mLayout.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        }

        holder.mLayout.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            selectedItem = itemArrayList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        });

    }

    public TypeObject getSelectedItem() {
        return selectedItem;
    }

    public void setSelectedItem(TypeObject selectedItem) {
        this.selectedItem = selectedItem;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.itemArrayList.size();
    }




    /**
     * Responsible for handling the data of each view
     */
    class viewHolders extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView    mName,
                    mPeople,
                    mTextprix;
        ImageView   mImage;
        LinearLayout mLayout;
        viewHolders(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            mPeople = itemView.findViewById(R.id.people);
            mName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            mLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.layout);
            mTextprix = itemView.findViewById(R.id.prixprix);

        }
    }
}





public class Utils {


    /**
     * Round a float value to a specific decimal place
     * @param amount - the value to round
     * @param decimalPlace - to what decimal place to round the amount to
     * @return rounded number
     */
    public BigDecimal round(float amount, int decimalPlace) {
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(Float.toString(amount));
        bd = bd.setScale(decimalPlace, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
        return bd;
    }


    /**
     * Returns array list with all of the driver rides available for this
     * application.
     * @param activity - activity that called this function
     * @return typeArrayList - array list with all the driver types
     */
    public static ArrayList<TypeObject> getTypeList(Activity activity){
        ArrayList<TypeObject> typeArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        typeArrayList.add(new TypeObject("type_1", activity.getResources().getString(R.string.type_1), activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_type_1), 3));


        return  typeArrayList;
    }


    public static TypeObject getTypeById(Activity activity, String id){
        ArrayList<TypeObject> typeArrayList = getTypeList(activity);
        for(TypeObject mType : typeArrayList){
            if(mType.getId().equals(id)){
                return mType;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

AND

```
public class TypeObject {

    String name, id;
    Drawable image;
    int people;

    public TypeObject(String id, String name, Drawable image, int people){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
        this.people = people;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Drawable getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getPeople() {
        return people;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the color of the text present inside the mLayout I think It might be white. Try changing it to someother color if it's white

Comment: i try it but it's not that

Comment: can you update your question with the complete adapter code ?

Comment: yes i just did. you can try to look?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem come from TypeAdapter Classe

at

```
       holder.mLayout.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        selectedItem = itemArrayList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    });
```